# JQUERY validation plugin + AJAX + PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I recently started learning AJAX for form submitting, but it seems that i'm still missing something essential, because the submitted data won't go to the PHP file like it's suppose to. I don't understand why it won't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <form class="form" action="../wp-content/themes/tempo/cfgs/js/scrollmagic/contact.php">
Eesnimi:
 <input name="eesnimi" id="eesnimi" class="required" type="text">
Perekonnanimi:
 <input name="pernimi" id="pernimi" class="required" type="text">
E-Post:
 <input name="email" id="email" class="required" type="email">
Telefoni number:
 <input name="nr" id="nr" class="required" type="text">
Teema:
 <input name="teema" id="teema" class="required" type="text">
 Sõnumi sisu:
  <textarea name="sisu" id="sisu" class="required"></textarea>
 <div></div>
  <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Edasta">
 </form>
</div>
```

JQUERY/AJAX

```
$('#sub').click(function(){
  $('.form').submit();
  var eesnimi = $('#eesnimi').val();
  var pernimi = $('#pernimi').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var nr = $('#nr').val();
  var teema = $('#teema').val();
  var sisu = $('#sisu').val();

    $('.form').validate({
        rules:{
          eesnimi: {
            required: true,
            nowhitespace: true,
            lettersonly: true
          },
          pernimi: {
            required: true,
            nowhitespace: true,
            lettersonly: true
          },
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },
          nr: {
            required: false,
            integer: true
          },
          teema: {
            required: true
          },
          sisu: {
            required: true
          }
        },
        messages:{
          eesnimi: {
            required: valituhiErr,
            nowhitespace: tuhikErr,
            lettersonly: nonumbersErr
          },
          pernimi: {
            required: valituhiErr,
            nowhitespace: tuhikErr,
            lettersonly: nonumbersErr
          },
          email: {
            required: valituhiErr,
            email: emailErr
          },
          nr: {
            required: valituhiErr,
            integer: onlynumbersErr
          },
          teema: {
            required: valituhiErr,
          },
          sisu: {
            required: valituhiErr,
          }
        },
        submitHandler: function(){
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "../wp-content/themes/tempo/cfgs/js/scrollmagic/contact.php",
             data: $('.form').serialize(),
             success: function (o) {
                 console.log(o);
             }
         });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I'm just experimenting, it seems that validation works correctly but the submit function won't, beceause the server won't recieve anything from my ajax request and it won't display anything on console either.

Comment: You're POSTing the data, and then printing out the GET query string data in your PHP. Try `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Yeah, thats just a typo, i already tried both ways, mybad for not fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

try this : jquery

```
var data = {
   eesnimi = $('#eesnimi').val();
 pernimi = $('#pernimi').val();
  email = $('#email').val();
   nr = $('#nr').val();
   teema = $('#teema').val();
  sisu = $('#sisu').val();
        };
  $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "JSON",
            url : "register.php",
            data : data,
            success : function(result)
            {

                if (result.hasOwnProperty('error') && result.error == '1'){
                    var html = '';


                    $.each(result, function(key, item){

                        if (key != 'error'){ 
                            html += '<li>'+item+'</li>';
                        }
                    });
                   //show in html
```

php

```
 eesnimi = $_POST['eesnimi']
 pernimi = ...
  email =...
   nr = ...
   teema = ...
  sisu = ...
//connect db
//sqlquery you want validate
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['eesnimi']==$eesnimi ){
        $errors['eesnimi '] = ...;
    }
// like this 
if (count($errors) > 1){
    $errors['error'] = 1;
    die (json_encode($errors));
}
//insert into db

}
```

hope this help

Comment: Thank you man! Something similar to this worked for me, thanks again!